# How to horizontally align 2 divs with space between

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I horizontally align these Divs: I would like the div id "leftDiv" on the left div id "rightdiv" on the right. I would like a little space between each divs

```
     <div  >
           <div id="leftDiv">

                <table id="mytable" class="table" style="width: 300px" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color:#C0DBE5">
                            <th>Order Quantity</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="mytableb">
                        <tr><td>1</td><td>$12</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>2</td><td>$14</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>5</td><td>20</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>10</td><td>$30</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
</div>

            <div id="rightdiv" >
                <h5 style="color:green"><b>Only $2 item! + $5  fee </b></h5>
                <h5 style="color:green"><b>Get item for <span style="color:#000">Test</span>,<span style="color:red">Test B</span> and other music sites...</b></h5>

                <h5 style="color:red"><b>Get your item now!</b></h5>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using CSS to style your items instead of using Inline Styles.

Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8A3Z/). I've added classes `left` and `right`, setting an actual width to the left div help the browser understand that there's space for another div to the right since **block level** elements like *div* take up 100% width normally.